# Timer doesn't restart after the wanted time java

Tags: java, timer, timertask

I have the following code. My problem is that the program is running only once, even though I want it to run every 5 seconds. Can you guide me to my mistake?

Basically the program has to check in a database the last two entries and make a difference between the timestamps.

In the end, it has to give a message to the user, if the time that passed is the needed one or not. This should run continously, but I was only able to make it run once.

Here is the code i have:

```
java.util.Timer timer = new java.util.Timer();

  public TimerChangeButtonBackground() {
     timer.schedule(new TimerTask(){
    public void run() 
        {


            try {
                 String DB_Connection = "jdbc:sqlserver://127.0.0.1:1433;databaseName=Dizertatie;instance=SQLServer;integratedSecurity=true;";
                Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver").newInstance();
                final Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_Connection);



                Statement state = conn.createStatement();

                ResultSet rs = state.executeQuery("set dateformat dmy; \n" +
"\n" +
"SELECT TOP 2 DIFF FROM  DIFF_CT ORDER BY Full_Time_Stamp DESC ");
                JOptionPanex.getRootFrame().dispose();
                if(rs.next()){
                    rs.next();
                    String value = rs.getString(1);
                    int difference = Integer.valueOf(value);

                    if (difference <= 5){

                    ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Hory\\Desktop\\likegreen.png");
                JOptionPanex.showConfirmDialog(
                        null,
                        "Part in target",
                        "In Target", JOptionPanex.OK_CANCEL_OPTION,JOptionPanex.CANCEL_OPTION, icon);

                System.out.printf("target");
                }
                    else{

                     ImageIcon icon2 = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Hory\\Desktop\\likered.png");
                JOptionPanex.showConfirmDialog(
                            null,
                        "Part NOT in target",
                        "Not in target",JOptionPanex.OK_CANCEL_OPTION,JOptionPanex.CANCEL_OPTION,icon2);
                    System.out.printf("NOtarget");
                    }

            }}catch(Exception e){

                System.out.println(e);
            }}},3,5000);  
     `
```

Comment: Have you got any error? As per `Timer`'s javadoc, "If the timer's task execution thread terminates unexpectedly, for example, because its stop method is invoked, any further attempt to schedule a task on the timer will result in an IllegalStateException, as if the timer's cancel method had been invoked."

Comment: No..I don't have errors. The only thing that I can add, is that the class is triggered by a button. So the execution starts when a button is pressed. Can it be a problem?

Comment: I don't think so, however I'm not experienced with timers. I seem to remember something about updating an UI from threads being possibly problematic. Have you checked that you had only one of your `printf`'s logs?

Comment: Yes. I have one, but then, after 5 seconds, I should have the second one..and so on..I am still looking on the Internet for maybe other ways to do it

Comment: Well the timer's javadoc suggests using a [`ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html) instead of Timer, maybe you should try it out. Or maybe someone will come here who knows what he's talking about, unlike me ;)

Comment: In case that helps, another possibility I had in mind is that your `TimerTask` might not complete in time for the next iteration to start. That seems unlikely though, and I didn't read anything describing this behavior when I cross-read the `Timer`'s javadoc.

Comment: It works somehow, after I've put a timer to the action of the button that calls the class. thanks